# Can't get value from table td with quotes

Tags: javascript

Here I am creating dynamic table

```
function addToMLContainer(id, mlName, mlAddress) {
    return '<td><s:text>' + mlName + ' ' + mlAddress + '</s:text></td>' +
        '<td hidden="hidden">' + id + '<input name="mlId" type="hidden"       value = "' + id + '" /></td>' +
        '<td hidden="hidden"><input name="mlFullName" type="hidden" value = "' + mlName + ' ' + mlAddress + '" /></td>' +
        '<td align="center"><img src="/delete.png" class="remove" onclick="this.closest(\'tr\').remove()"/></td>'
}
```

And here I am getting value of tr:

```
var t = document.getElementById("AddedMlsContainer");

for (var i = 1, row; row = t.rows[i]; i++) {

    selectedMerchants = selectedMerchants + " " + row.cells[2].children[0].value + "\n";

}
```

The problem is I can't get value with double or single quotes like `<I'm "blabla">`

Comment: An input value cannot contain double quotes in HTML, when double quotes are already used to enclose the attribute value itself.

Comment: try escaping the quotes or use html entities for the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it by removing input field and unnesessary td:

```
'<td>' + mlName + ' ' + mlAddress + '</td>' +
        '<td hidden="hidden">' + id + '<input name="mlId" type="hidden" value = "' + id + '" /></td>' +
        '<td align="center"><img src="/delete.png" class="remove" onclick="this.closest(\'tr\').remove()"/></td>'
```

Then I used innerHtml

var t = document.getElementById("AddedMlsContainer");

```
for (var i = 1, row; row = t.rows[i]; i++) {

    selectedMerchants = selectedMerchants + " " + row.cells[0].innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g,'') + "\n";

}
```